# React / TS: Throttle function but also set state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, throttling

I have a React functional component. There's an `input` field with the `value` that is set using `useState`. I have a simple standard `function throttle(callback: Function, delay = 1000)`

**Requirements:**

1. Set search term (state) via `onChange` event handler.
2. Throttle the callback (search()) function call.

I can do one the other, but not both. while banging my head against the wall.

**[Link to Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-forked-myllgn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

(FYI, I am not interested in debouncing.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `useRef` to store the value of `shouldWait` should be the way to go. Additionally, `useCallback` can be used on the `throttle` function to memoize it.

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState, useMemo, useRef, useCallback } from "react";

/*
Requirements:
1. Set search term (state), 
2. Throttle the callback (search()) function call.

There are two functions that should be interesting, both onChange handlers: 
 * handleOnChange (Does not satisfy Requirement 2)
 * throttledOnChangeHandler (Does not satisfy Requirement 1)
*/
export const Searchbox: React.FC = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const shouldWait = useRef<boolean>(false);

  const throttle = useCallback((callback: Function, delay = 1000, ...args: any[]) => {
      if (shouldWait.current) return;

      callback(...args);
      shouldWait.current = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        shouldWait.current = false;
      }, delay);
  }, []);

  function search() {
    console.log(new Date().getSeconds())
    console.log("Searching term:", searchTerm);
  }

  const handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    throttle(search);
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Search!</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Blah!"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This works, but why is it good to use `useRef`? I am still learning and not too familiar with useRef.

I got it working with `useState` with your throttle() for inspiration, and it works too!

Comment: `useRef` is better in this case because updating the value of the `current` property in the ref does not cause a re-render. `useState` may work in this case, but whenever you are updating the value of the state using the `setState` function,a re-render is taking place. Another thing is if some other effect causes your component to re-render, `useRef` will be able to preserve that value between the renders. So you could say it is more optimized in this case to use `useRef` instead of `useState`.